# How to gain reference to a clicked Hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I understand that I can use the .click() method on a hyperlink element.  But how do I know which element was clicked?  First I have to gain reference to the hyperlink's ID.

So lets say I have a page of hyperlinks like this in view source:

```
<a href="addButton1" href="...someurl"><img src="somebutton"></a>
<a href="addButton2" href="...someurl"><img src="somebutton"></a>
<a href="addButton3" href="...someurl"><img src="somebutton"></a>
<a href="addButton4" href="...someurl"><img src="somebutton"></a>
```

when a user clicks addButton1, how do I even know it's addButton1 that was clicked in the first place so that I can now apply a .click() event on it?

Answer (score 5):

To observe click event for all links on a page:

```
$("a").click(function (e) { 
      // this function fires anytime a hyperlink is clicked

      e.preventDefault();

      // reference $(this) to get at the specific 
      // link that fired the event, such as:
      alert($(this).attr('href')); // display href value of the hyperlink
    });
```

To observe click events for a subset of links on a page:

Add a class to your hyperlink tags. Example: `<a class="observe" href="#">`

And change the above function event signature to:

```
$("a.observe").click(function (e) { ... });
```

Comment: what if I don't want to run javascript for every hyperlink?  I'd be making the user check and run this function every time.  There is only a subset of hyperlinks that this function will apply to outside the many other hyperlinks on my page (top nav, left nave, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to differentiate between links is to add a class or id to them. Then you can set event handling like so:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:" class="myClass" id="myId">Click here!</a>
```

jQuery can be done in one of two (ok, there are more than two, but here are two) ways:

```
$('#myId').click(function() { doSomething() });
$('.myClass').click(function() { doSomething() });
```